# Display the changes in a file only without commit messages or anything else

Tags: git, logging, diff

I want to display only the changes in a file and just that, without commit messages or hashes or anything else.

Suppose that my file starts empty. Then a commit adds one line to it, and the file now looks like this

```
foo
```

A second commit that removes that line and adds a new one is made

```
bar
```

The third and last commit adds another line

```
bar
baz
```

The output should be

```
+foo
-foo
+bar
+baz
```

For my specific use case, I just need to find any content that made it into the file (so ideally `foo` should be displayed once); I don't care when it was added or by who, but any answer that can get me close to this is appreciated and I will modify the output to display just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Given this repository:

```
$ git log -p | grep -v Author
commit 3841ace5539820cf8a45edd7033bdd4e5edf3ab2
Date:   Sat Jun 9 18:22:15 2018 -0700

    Add baz to test.txt

diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 5716ca5..e2994c5 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 bar
+baz

commit df9de6c79d2374741792b9e5762468f83ab857b8
Date:   Sat Jun 9 18:21:58 2018 -0700

    Remove foo add bar to test.txt

diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 257cc56..5716ca5 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-foo
+bar

commit 74c1beb71d08020635f39edd80dff15ce279742e
Date:   Sat Jun 9 18:21:21 2018 -0700

    Add foo to test.txt

diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index e69de29..257cc56 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+foo

commit a970fd59229f791f2f3a7be97014843e55b651d3
Date:   Sat Jun 9 18:20:58 2018 -0700

    Add test.txt

diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
```

This command produces the output you're looking for:

```
$ git log -p --reverse --unified=0 --pretty=format: test.txt \
   | grep ^[+-] \
   | grep -vE '^[+-]{3}'
+foo
-foo
+bar
+baz
```

I wasn't able to find a pure git log command that does the trick. However, assuming you're not interested in context lines, using `grep` to post-process the output does the trick.

The idea is to filter the output leaving only the change lines (i.e. starts with `+` or `-`) and then filter out the before/after legend (i.e. `--- a/test.txt` and `+++ b/test.txt`). Granted, this could prove problematic if there's content in the file(s) where there are lines that start with `++`.